# Como funciona o "position: sticky"?

Tags: html, css, css3

O `sticky` é um novo valor da propriedade `position` e eu li um pouco e entendi que com ele é possível criarmos elementos HTML que se comportam em um momento como `position: fixed` e em outro como `position: relative` dependendo de um valor do offset.

Mas não entendi como isto funciona na pratica, eu também gostaria de saber sobre a compatibilidade, qual o suporte e quando vou precisar dos prefixos como `-webkit-` e `-moz-`.

Answer (score 6):

São várias perguntas em uma só, vamos por parte.

- *Mas não entendi como isto funciona na pratica...*

Aqui estão dois exemplos do `sticky` funcionando [Sticky 1](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/sticky.html). [Sticky 02](http://jsfiddle.net/daker/ecpTw/light/)
Note que ao realizar o `scroll`da página a `div` do topo que contém a descrição acompanha o `scroll` e ao encontrar outra `div` ela muda. O que acontece é que o elemento é tratado como relativo `position: relative;` até que ele chegue ao limite especificado, no caso dos exemplos `top: 10px;`, depois disso ele é tratado como fixo `position: fixed;`

- *eu também gostaria de saber sobre a compatibilidade...*

Chrome, I.E, Opera - Não suportado;
Firefox (Gecko) - Versão 32 (32.0);
Safari - Versão 6.1 `-webkit-`

- *qual o suporte e quando vou precisar dos prefixos como `-webkit-` e `-moz-`*

Safari - Versão 6.1 `-webkit-`

Sugiro a leitura da documentação em [Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: Não são várias, são só 3 perguntas em uma só e no final das contas 2 são tecnicamente a mesma, prefixo e compatibilidade se referem a mesma situação, e comportamento da propriedade é o basico da pergunta.

Comment: Essa parte do suporte está meio esquisita. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky - e é static e fixed, nada de relative. Só é relative quando se trata de **tabelas**.